# Grid how to find the index of the first position of the next row given a starting index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, grid, formula

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
```

assume there is an array like a css grid with 15 elements like above, there are five columns and 3 rows, and starting index is 0

given the index of **any** element, how do you find the index of the first position that is in the next row ?

for example,

index 4 returns 5
index 6 returns 10
index 2 returns 5
index 11 returns 15
index 0 returns 5
index 14 returns 15

my formula is **not** working

```
const colPosition = index % colCount;
const rowPosition = Math.floor(index / colCount);
const answer = index + (colCount - colPosition) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const colPosition = index % colCount
const rowPosition = Math.floor( (index - colPosition) / colCount)
const answer = (rowPosition + 1) * colCount
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand question properly but you can try this

```js
let arr = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
];

let a = value(7, arr);
console.log(a);

function value(index, array) {
  let flat = array.flat();
  let z = ((index + 1) / flat.length * array.length);
  if (z > array.length) {
    //return -1;
    return (flat.slice().reverse()[0]) + 1;
  }
  if (z % 1 > 0) {
    z = z - z % 1 + 1;
  }
  return array[z][0];
};
```